# Emitting events through a module in React Native on Android

Tags: react-native

In Swift, React Native has an event emitter pattern that is scoped to the module level, like this.

```
class MyModule :  RCTEventEmitter  {
    @objc
    func rnMethod(){
        self.sendEvent(withName: "EventName" , body: "something")
    }
}
```

Is there an Android equivalent to this? The best I've found so far is a global variant which was deprecated in iOS, like so:

```
fun rnMethod(){
    val eventEmitter = reactContext.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter::class.java) as DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter
    eventEmitter.emit(event.eventName, context)
}
```

Comment: This is what I use currently, and it does the job for me

Comment: What you are using is correct, and not deprecated for Android

Comment: Any hint that they would be moving in a similar direction for Android in the future? There are some commits that imply that they wanted to but it didn't go anywhere.